# Вылазит ошибка NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout, помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ее

Tags: python, вконтакте, timeout, музыка

Нашел на просторах интернета код программы, скачивающей музыку из ВК(https://github.com/mihaleva-po/kod_music.git -- **ссылка на полный код**).

Работа программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводится ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Код:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
        urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(http.cookiejar.CookieJar()),
        urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler())

#Сбор нужной информации
print("VK Music Downloader")
login = input("Телефон либо email > ")
password = input("Пароль > ")
track = input("Исполнитель и наименование композиции > ")
filename = track+ ".mp3"
track = urllib.parse.quote(track)

#Авторизация
print("Авторизация...")
parser = FormParser()
response = str(opener.open("http://m.vk.com/").read())
parser.feed(response)
parser.params["email"] =login
parser.params["pass"] = password
response = opener.open(parser.url, urllib.parse.urlencode(parser.params).encode())
parser.close()

#Поиск
print("Поиск композиции...")
response = str(opener.open("http://m.vk.com/audio?act=search&q=%s" % track).read())#эта переменная не использует, или она не нужна или про нее забыли
seacher = TrackSearch()
seacher.feed(response)

#Загрузка
print("Загрузка > %s" % filename)
with urllib.request.urlopen(seacher.url) as data, \ #в этом место показывает ошибку
     open(filename, 'wb') as fout:
     fout.write(data.read())

seacher.close()
input("Загрузка закончена")
```

Буду очень признателен, если поможете решить эту проблему)